# How to determine if an irrational expression is a perfect square?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

Let $a,c\in\Bbb R$ and $b,d \in \Bbb N$. Is there a way to determine if

$$a\sqrt b+c\sqrt d$$

can be written as

$$(e+f)^2,$$

with $e,f\in\Bbb R$? If so, is there a way to find what $e$ and $f$, given $a, b,c, $ and $d$?

For example, in my math textbook, it says that $$32-16\sqrt 3=(2\sqrt 6-2\sqrt 2)^2,$$ but they didn't explain how they got there. If someone can explain, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Your general question is **too** general.  Specifically, any non-negative real number can be written as $(e+f)^2$ for $e,f \in \mathbb{R},$ just by setting $e+f$ equal to its square root.  I don't think you mean that.  The specific question, of course, can still be of interest ("How do we find a 'simplified form' of the square root of something like $32-16\sqrt{3}$?")

Comment: So should I just delete the top portion of my question and just leave in the second question?

Comment: I would think so, yes.  It's possible someone knows how to rephrase the general question to be more interesting (probably in terms of algebraic number theory), but I personally don't know the appropriate way to do that.

Comment: The example in your math textbook was probably deduced by starting from RHS.

Answer (score 1):

The question is, what form are $e$ and $f$ to take? Otherwise, the problem is trivially solved since we can write any positive real number $r$ as $(\sqrt r)^2=(1+s)^2$ for some suitable $s,$ for example.

If we take a cue from the example given in your text, then you probably want $e,\,f$ to be the square roots of rationals, so that the question reduces to finding out when a binomial quadratic surd is the square root of another. That is, we want to find conditions on rational $p,\,q$ such that $$\sqrt{\sqrt p\pm\sqrt q}=\sqrt m\pm\sqrt n,$$ for some rational $m,\,n,$ which is standard fare. Square both sides to obtain $$\sqrt p\pm\sqrt q=m+n\pm2\sqrt{mn}.$$ Then we must have one of $\sqrt p$ or $\sqrt q$ to be rational, clearly, and this must be equal to $m+n.$ Secondly we must have $\pm2\sqrt{mn}$ equal to the other summand on LHS. You may examine these conditions further to deduce finer restraints.

Answer (score 0):

First, $x\sqrt y=\sqrt{x^2y}$ so we can simplify general case to $(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2=c+2d$. Now we can obtain two equations to find $a$ and $b$: $a+b=c$  and $ab=d$. This system is easy to solve using substitution $a=c-b$ which leads to a quadratic equation $(c-b)b=d$. The system may or may not have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show a method for finding some such roots, which should apply to your example.  I'll instead apply the method to find $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}}$.

So, suppose $x = \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{5}}$.  Then $x^2 = 3 + \sqrt{5}$; $x^2 - 3 = \sqrt{5}$; and so $(x^2 - 3)^2 = 5$.  Expanding, we get:
$$x^4 - 6x^2 + 4 = 0.$$

Now, let us observe that $(x^2 + 2)^2 = x^4 + 4x^2 + 4$ which is close to matching the left hand side.  So, using the difference of squares formula, this is equivalent to $$(x^2 + 2)^2 - 10x^2 = (x^2 + 2)^2 - (x\sqrt{10})^2 = (x^2 + x\sqrt{10} + 2) (x^2 - x\sqrt{10} - 2) = 0.$$

However, by the quadratic formula, the roots of $x^2 + x \sqrt{10} + 2 = 0$ are $x = \frac{-\sqrt{10} \pm \sqrt{2}}{2}$, and the roots of $x^2 - x\sqrt{10} + 2 = 0$ are $x = \frac{\sqrt{10} \pm \sqrt{2}}{2}$.  Thus, overall we have $x = \frac{\pm\sqrt{10} \pm\sqrt{2}}{2}$.  It only remains to check which of these expressions actually is positive, and also gives $3 + \sqrt{5}$ when squared.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the reals there no point in talking about "perfect" squares as for any $x \ge 0$ then *will* be a $y$ so that $y^2 = x$ and $y = \sqrt x$.

So if you want $(e+f)^2 = a\sqrt{b}+ c\sqrt {d}>0$ then just let $y= \sqrt {a\sqrt b + c\sqrt d}$ and let $e= $ anything and $f= y-e$.  That's it.

As to how the book got $32-16\sqrt 3=(2\sqrt 6-2\sqrt 2)^2$ that is *very* specific to those integers.  (I'm more curious as to why rather than how) but:

Going from $2\sqrt 6 - 2\sqrt 2$ to noting that $(2\sqrt 6 - 2\sqrt 2)^2 = (2\sqrt 6)^2 - 2(2\sqrt 62\sqrt 2) + (2\sqrt 2)^2 = 4*6 - 8\sqrt {12} + 4*2=32 - 4\sqrt {4*3} = 32 - 16\sqrt 3$ is straightforward.

As for going from $32-16\sqrt 3$... well:

$\sqrt{32 - 16\sqrt 3}= 4(\sqrt {2 -\sqrt 3})$

.... so I guess the question is... how do you go from $\sqrt{a \pm \sqrt b}$ to $\sqrt x \pm \sqrt y$.

Okay.... if $\sqrt x \pm \sqrt y = \sqrt{2-\sqrt 3}$ then

$x + y \pm2\sqrt{xy}=x+y\pm \sqrt{4xy}= 2- \sqrt 3$.

So we need $x+y= 2$ and $4xy= 3$ or $xy = \frac 34$.  And as we are subtracting we need $x > y$.

If we assume rational values so that $x =\frac ab$ and $y=\frac cd$ and so $\frac{ad+ cb}{bd}  = 2$ and $\frac {ac}{bd}=\frac 34$ and as we need.

Trial and error but if $b=d =2$ then we need $ac = 3$ and $2a + 2c= 8$ or $a+c = 4$ and $a > c$.  so $a =3$ and $c = 1$ and

$\sqrt{2 -\sqrt 3} = \sqrt {\frac 32} - \sqrt{\frac 12}$.

$\sqrt{32-16\sqrt 3} = 4(\sqrt {\frac 32} - \sqrt{\frac 12})=$

$2(\sqrt {\frac {4*3}2} - \sqrt{\frac {4}2})= 2(\sqrt 3- \sqrt {2})=$

$2\sqrt 6 - 2\sqrt 2$

Comment: The problem was(I think):  A right triangle has legs 4-$2\sqrt 3$ and $2$. What is the hypotenuse?

Comment: The hyptentuse then is $\sqrt {(4-2\sqrt 3)^2 + 2^2} =\sqrt{(4^2 - 2*4*2\sqrt 3 + (2\sqrt 3)^2) + 4} =\sqrt{(16-16\sqrt 3 + 4*3) + 4}= \sqrt{32-16\sqrt 3}=4\sqrt{2-\sqrt 3}$.  Which is good enough. There's no *need* to put it as $2\sqrt 6 - 2\sqrt 2$ but you can verify by doing it that that is so.

Comment: Oh that's what I got too but the book simplifies it to $2\sqrt 6-2\sqrt 2$. Is the book wrong or is it still acceptable?

Comment: Since $(2\sqrt 6 - 2\sqrt 2)^2 =32 - 16\sqrt 3$ (just do it) the $2\sqrt 6 - 2\sqrt 2 =\sqrt {32 - 16\sqrt 3}$ so both are correct.  Both are acceptable unless there's a guy in front of you saying "I don't accept that".

Comment: If you want to turn $32 - 16\sqrt{3} = (a + b\sqrt 3)^2$ then we need $a^2+3b^2 = 32$ and $-16\sqrt{3} = 2ab\sqrt 3$. Trial and error and clever insight will show you $32 = 4*8=1*8 + 3*8$ and so if $a^2 = b^2 = 8$ and $ab=-8$ we have it.  $b=\sqrt 8 =2\sqrt 2$ and $a=-\sqrt 8=-2\sqrt 2$ and   $\sqrt{32-16\sqrt 3}= 2\sqrt 2\sqrt 3 -2\sqrt 2 =2\sqrt 6- 2\sqrt 2$.  But I don't see any reason to *try* to do that.